# Last item in layout not appear

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I am working on android app 
and i have cart activity which have multi row of products
and then the total of cart and button to continue..

This layout have top and buttom bars and then Scrollview have linearLayout as child...

This child contain:

- Recyclerview
- Textboxes
- Button

My problem is: I cant scroll to the last item in my layout (The Button) .

### This is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/progress_rec"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overview_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/backgroudn"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/tt"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "70dp"
                android:elevation="12dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_action_bar"
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:elevation="12dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnActionBar11"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width = "0dp"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/cart"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tvActionBar"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnActionBarEnd11"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/first">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/no_data"
                        android:text="@string/no_data"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:foregroundGravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/progress"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/no_data"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone" />



                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/cartContentList"
                        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:id="@+id/totalLayout">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:weightSum="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                                android:text="@string/total"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                                android:text="@string/zero_dollar"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                android:gravity="center"

                                android:id="@+id/tvTotal"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                                android:text="@string/continue_"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
                                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:id="@+id/btnContinue" />
                        </LinearLayout>




                    </LinearLayout>




                </LinearLayout>


            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/any"
            android:background="@drawable/white_menu_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:elevation="24dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "40dp"
                android:elevation="12dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/end"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_1"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/btnMyOrder"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_orders_1"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/notifications_1"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="18dp"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/side_menu_1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"/>



            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "20dp"
                android:elevation="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/end1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gr1Home1"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/component1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gr2Notification1"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/component1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gr3Message1"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/component1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gr4Calender1"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/component1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>



            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my Cart Activity XMl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cart_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cart_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/abl_main1"
            layout="@layout/app_header_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_item_count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/abl_main1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_count_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/my_cart"
                android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/my_cart"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_9E"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_total"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/total_caps"
                android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_item_count">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="60dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_listing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rcv_cart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        style="@style/CardView.Light"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_playable"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:text="@string/cart_total"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_cart_total"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:text="@string/total"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_sub_total"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:text="@string/discount"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_discount"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:text="@string/dilivery"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_delivery"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:text="@string/total_payable"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_total_payable"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:maxLines="2"
                                    android:text="@string/tax_and_shipping_calculated"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_15"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                            </LinearLayout>


                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin5dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:text="@string/add_order_note"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/ed_order_note"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_transperant_bg_app_color_border"
                                    android:focusable="true"
                                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                    android:gravity="top|left"
                                    android:hint="@string/how_can_we_help_you"
                                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                                    android:lines="3"
                                    android:maxLines="3"
                                    android:overScrollMode="always"
                                    android:padding="@dimen/margin5dp"
                                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_item" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rr_empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_item_count"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_backgorund_circle_cart"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_background_icon_cart"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@mipmap/iv_red_heart"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_empty_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_size_20"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/your_bag_is_empty"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_empty_sub_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_10"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/item_added_to_bag"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_9E"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_shopping_now"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_transperant_bg_app_color_border_new"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_shopping_now"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_password"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_10"
                        android:text="@string/shopping_now"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_order_place"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_place_order"
            android:background="@color/light_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_place_order"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_place_order_total"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/text_item"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <com.wpa3.productshopify.util.RippleView
                rv_centered="true"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                app:rv_type="rectangle"
                app:rv_zoom="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_place_order"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_round_corner_rectangle"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/place_order"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </com.wpa3.productshopify.util.RippleView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Right now i'm busy so did not seen your XML but check my code snippet.
Hope this may help you

Comment: Thank u very much.. it was helpfull!